# Pagination functionality in laravel, Issue: Call to a member function paginate() on array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

Laravel Framework - using version 5.4: If I used raw query as shown below in User.php controller and making paginate(3) as shown below. But it is giving error as "Call to a member function paginate() on array". solution please.

```
DB::select("select u.email,u.name,u.created_at from users u where u.id in (select max(ui.id) from users ui where ui.status = 0) order by ui.id desc")->paginate(3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will do the job

```
 DB::table('users as u')->select(['u.email','u.name','u.created_at'])->whereRaw("u.id in (select max(ui.id) from users ui where ui.status = 0)")->orderBy("ui.id","desc")->paginate(3);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Divyank Munjapara.

Answer (score 0):

yeah because your query ain't returning an object its returning an array. Try to use laravel query builder or Eloquent.

```
$users = DB::table('users')->paginate(15); //query builder example
$users = User::where('votes', '>', 100)->paginate(15); //eloquent example
```

Also make sure your query is working fine.